# Git Branch name won't show up on Mac Terminal

Tags: bash, git

I added the following lines to my Mac's `~/.bash_profile`:

```sh
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

#Variables
userName="\u"
fullPath="\w"
systemName="\h"

#'$(tput setaf 14)' allows coloring for the prompt
#that immediately follows it. 14 is the color aqua.
#A list of colors can be accessed below:
#https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/

#`$(tput sgr0)` stops the text coloring from continuing on.

#Personalized Terminal
PS1="\[$(tput setaf 118)\]${userName}\[$(tput setaf 3)\]@${systemName}\[$(tput setaf 14)\]${fullPath}\[$(tput setaf 222)\]\[$(parse_git_branch)\]\[$(tput setaf 160)\]$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
export PS1;

#export PS1="\u@\h \W\[\033[32m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\] $ "

#------- Aliases -------

#Open Sublime Text Editor
alias subl="open -a /Applications/Sublime\ Text.app"
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

The Terminal styling looks good, but my `parse_git_branch` doesn't show the name of my git branches.  I screwed up in defining the `PS1` value, but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: Comment out `Personalized Terminal`?

Comment: @Keldorn Did that; no luck

Comment: Well, when I have similar problems I divide and conquer (i.e., throw out half of the PS1 definition and see whether it now works, etc.) Also, obviously, check whether `parse_git_branch()` works at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this :

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=$(cat << 'EOF'
git_prompt=$(git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/')
EOF
)

#Variables
userName="\u"
fullPath="\w"
systemName="\h"

PS1="\[$(tput setaf 118)\]${userName}\[$(tput setaf 3)\]@${systemName}\[$(tput setaf 14)\]${fullPath}\[$(tput setaf 222)\]\[\$git_prompt\]\[$(tput setaf 160)\]$ \[$(tput sgr0)\]"
```